# How to append log data into xml files?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having a logfile in shared folder . ( Initially it will have only root element.).

Whenever users execute a powershell script following log data has to be appended to XML.

```
<VM>
    <VMName>Fresh_R2VM</VMName>
    <AccessedBy>David</AccessedBy>
    <AccessedDate>Today's date</AccessedDate>
    <AccessedTime>current Time</AccessedTime>
</VM>
```

My XML log file will be initially like this

```
<VirtualMachines version="1.0">

</virtualMachines>
```

Once the first user (david) executed the script, My log file should be like this.

```
<VirtualMachines version="1.0">
<VM>
    <VMName>Fresh_R2VM</VMName>
    <AccessedBy>David</AccessedBy>
    <AccessedDate>Today's date</AccessedDate>
    <AccessedTime>current Time</AccessedTime>
</VM>
</virtualMachines>
```

If david executes second time, another one entry should be appended.

```
<VirtualMachines version="1.0">
    <VM>
        <VMName>Fresh_R2VM</VMName>
        <AccessedBy>David</AccessedBy>
        <AccessedDate>Today's date</AccessedDate>
        <AccessedTime>current Time</AccessedTime>
    </VM>

    <VM>
        <VMName>Fresh_R2VM</VMName>
        <AccessedBy>David</AccessedBy>
        <AccessedDate>Today's date</AccessedDate>
        <AccessedTime>current Time</AccessedTime>
    </VM>
    </virtualMachines>
```

I was trying to achieve this using template xml file then clone the template to log file and update the contents. But it leaves one empty  tag. I managed to delete using removechild property.

But i am not able to append the contents every time.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Using XML for log files is a bad approach, there is a high cost especially if the log file gets large; more below.

A solution:

```
$file = Resolve-Path 'logfile.xml'
$output = [xml](Get-Content $file)
$vmNode = $output.DocumentElement

$newNode = [xml]@"
  <VM>
    <VMName>Fresh_R2VM</VMName>
    <AccessedBy>David</AccessedBy>
    <AccessedDate>$([DateTime]::Today)</AccessedDate>
    <AccessedTime>$([DateTime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss'))</AccessedTime>
  </VM>
"@

# Need to move the VM node from document newNode to the output document
$newNode = $output.ImportNode($newNode.DocumentElement, $true)
$vmNode.appendChild($newNode) | out-null

$output.Save($file)
```

**Performance**: Every time this adds a new node it loads and completely parses the existing document to then append one node, and then saves the whole document. Each append will take longer than the previous one. With a few thousand nodes this might be significant, with a few hundred thousand it certainly will be. And the parsed XML starts to become a major memory overhead – `XmlDocument` objects representing non-trivial XML documents need a lot of space.

**Alternatives**

1. Use a text file. Only the new data is written directly at the end (open file, move write position to end and write). This shows no degradation with file size, files with megabytes of content can have more data appended just as fast as a file of a new kilobytes. Additionally tools to search the file (eg. PowerShell's `Select-String` can process the file incrementally – again not needing to read in the whole file).
2. This is something of a hack: use a DTD and XML Entity. `LogFile.xml` contains a DTD defining an external entity referencing `LogFileContent.xml-data`. The `<VirtualMachines>` node in `LogFile.xml` then uses that entity to import `LogFileContent.xml-data` as its children. This means that  `LogFileContent.xml-data` does not need to be a valid document (does not need its root element). *But* it does mean that any tools processing `LogFile.xml` need to process that DTD (eg. .NET, and thus PowerShell, XML support disables external entities by default).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance buddy. I decided to go with Text file as log file.

Comment: I'm interested at the alternative 2. Someone got a link to good examples and explanations ? thanks

Comment: @Michael Kay: Do you have any post or some thing about alternative 2. If you don't have post , Is it possible for you to update sample as another answer?